# Ember 2.0 - views for pages

Tags: ember.js, view

I am used to put some jquery code in View files, that I create for pages.

For instance:

1. I have the route `this.route('buildings');`
2. Next create the view file app/views/buildings.js

   ```
   import Ember from "ember";

   export default Ember.View.extend(Ember.TargetActionSupport, {
      didInsertElement: function () {
        //jquery here
      }
   });
   ```

But now with Ember 2.0 we have no such ability, what should I do?

Comment: Kit is correct, though routeable components is the true step forward, you can just build up a component in the meantime.  https://github.com/ef4/rfcs/blob/routeable-components/active/0000-routeable-components.md

Comment: @Kingpin2k Yupp, the current state is pretty awkward, but what to do. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ember 2.0.0 you can still do the following:

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['customClassName'],
  didInsertElement: function() {
    alert('did insert element')
  }
});

App.BuildingsView = Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['customClassName2'],
  didInsertElement: function() {
    alert('did insert element2');
  }
});
```

See this [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/navofiveke/edit?html,js,console,output) for a working example.

P.S. Comment by Robert Jackson: "Using a component as ApplicationView will allow customization of classNames and whatnot, but is definitely going to have a number of negative results as well (for example controller is not correct)." https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11486#issuecomment-131366332

Comment: o.O I did not know that, is that sanctioned from embers side?

Comment: I am not sure. But it works currently. The way to go is routable components but no one knows for sure how they would look like.

Comment: Follow comments from team members on this topic here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11486#issuecomment-131366332

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a component. In **components/my-component.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    // jquery here.
  }
});
```

In your template:

```
{{my-component}}
```

Or:

```
{{#my-component}}
   Stuff
{{/my-component}}
```

Comment: As I know, this way I need to map every action I created. It's so sad =(

Comment: I'm not sure of your use case, but most of the time, jQuery should be tied to a specific component, and not to the view/route itself.  Also, see if you can tie the things you're accomplishing with jQuery to controller logic instead--many times, the view state can respond to a property instead of being manipulated manually with jQuery.

Comment: @mpowered If it's a widget, sure. There's quite a lot of javascript that do whole page enhancements like meterialize, fastclick and numerous other things. It's not that exceptional of a use case.